# Convert this Character string to Date in r

Tags: r

I have the data in character format as " Mar 26, 2015 7:46:22 PM CDT " I have convert this into a Date format and also fetch the month, year and day separately.
Also is it possible to conevert it into a integer format.

Please advice.

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct("Mar 26, 2015 7:46:22 PM CDT", format="%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")`

Comment: Can we convert Dates into integer values as we see in excel

Comment: `as.numeric(x)` converts a `Date`-`POSIXct` object to numeric, but I don't know excel and don't know _how_ you want to convert it. Please make an example.

Comment: I am unable to mark nicolas repy as answer. Please suggest me so that I can close this ticket.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to make an answer out of my comment and you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the format of the input string. Try:

```
as.POSIXct("Mar 26, 2015 7:46:22 PM CDT", format="%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: Although note this format string does not enable processing of the timezone (the result seems to default to the user's local timezone). A non-trivial solution to that issue is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877010/reading-timestamp-data-in-r-from-multiple-time-zones