# Converting time string with abbreviated timezone info in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data file that has timezone info in the datetime field. It looks something like this

```
"Wed May 18 13:42:29 MDT 2016"
```

I'm trying to convert this to a POSIXct object. Unfortunately `%Z` is allowed only for output.  For eg.

```
> timestr <- "Wed May 18 13:42:29 MDT 2016"
> tm.posixct <- as.POSIXct(timestr, tz="US/Mountain", format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S MDT %Y")
```

My data file contains `MDT` or `MST`, hence I can't use that in the format string.   Is there anyway to use the `TZ` info in that timefield for conversion instead of doing string manipulation and removing the timezone info before passing it to `as.POSIXct`?

Comment: You should have a look at similar question there:     Reading timestamp data in R from multiple time zones    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877010/reading-timestamp-data-in-r-from-multiple-time-zones

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like that will work for me.  Since I know that all the timestamps are from Mountain tz, I just removed the abbreviated tz name for the time being.  That works for me too.