# How to transfer to date time using lubridate?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Given a date-time:

> "Tue May 01 23:02:50 GMT+03:00 2018"

How can I transfer it to normal ddmmyyyy hh:mm:ss format?

I have tried `as.date` - got `NA`.
Tried with `parse_date_time` - same result.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lubridate, you could do

```
time <- as_datetime("Tue May 01 23:02:50 GMT+03:00 2018", 
            format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S GMT+03:00 %Y", 
            tz = "Etc/GMT-3")
time
[1] "2018-05-01 23:02:50 +03"
```

Then if you want to see it in your timezone you could do something like

```
with_tz(time, tzone = "America/New_York")
[1] "2018-05-01 16:02:50 EDT"
```

where the tzone argument would be your timezone.

If there are different timezones in your data other than GMT+3:00, this won't work though. If this is the case, you can check out [Reading timestamp data in R from multiple time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877010/reading-timestamp-data-in-r-from-multiple-time-zones).