# Parsing datetimes with timezones in words

Tags: r, lubridate

Is there anything in R that can parse a datetime string containing a timezone in standard words?  strptime can handle a signed numeric (eg +0200), but an alpha string returns NA, eg:

```
> strptime("Jun 23, 2022 04:00:01.12345678 Romance Summer Time", format = "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%OS %z")
[1] NA
```

For lubridate I seem to have to pass the tz as an argument in the function call, rather than the data, but I've tagged it anyway, just in case.

Comment: The names that R knows about can be seen by running `OlsonNames()` but the name in the question is not  one of them.

Comment: How about `strptime(sub('Romance Summer Time', '+0100', "Jun 23, 2022 04:00:01.12345678 Romance Summer Time"), format = "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%OS %z")` ?

Comment: Yeah, R doesn't "speak" those types of zones, but it does have them in its source, in [`src/extra/tzone/registerTZ.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/master/src/extra/tzone/registryTZ.c).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading timestamp data in R from multiple time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877010/reading-timestamp-data-in-r-from-multiple-time-zones).

Comment: @M--, the dupe link references TZs within `OlsonNames()`, this question is about the _other_ kind of TZ (is it just windows that uses these formally?).

Comment: @r2evans honestly I don't think this a dupe, that's why I left my mjolnir at home :)

Comment: (I had to look that one up ... so true.) Yup, I thought it might be that way, but sometimes people start voting to close based on a comment like that without really looking at the content. I thought I'd chime in and discourage that (for _that_ link).

Comment: I find working this this type of TZ to be a bit frustrating, since it bakes in (at times _inconsistently_) whether it is DST or not, in the time zone. While that's kind of nice, it's also more to have to parse and figure out, where instead the presence of DST should be determined by the timestamp itself based on the base zone. It's a good thing DST is constant over time ... oh wait, nope, forget that.

Comment: FYI, a fairly parseable version of many timezones can be found at https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guitarrapc/15f04fa68e5766f1dfff681adb3cc640/raw/1f9e5a77717e8a06dbeeab5fade02b24a6d0e1f3/ListTimeZoneTable.md ... not necessarily an authoritative source, but it works (for now).